# CA2208 when throwing ArgumentOutOfRangeException when using class field as argument

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis

I'm throwing an ArgumentOutOfRangeException when validating correct enum values:

```
internal class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    private readonly MyEnum _myEnum;

    public MyClass(MyEnum myEnum) => _myEnum = myEnum;

    public String MyString
    {
        get
        {
            switch (_myEnum)
            {
                case MyEnum.A:
                    return "A";
                case MyEnum.B:
                    return "B";
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("_myEnum");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting a CA2208 error when building:

> CA2208    Method 'MyCLass.MyString.get()' passes '_myEnum' as the 'paramName' argument to a 'ArgumentOutOfRangeException' constructor.
>   Replace this argument with one of the method's parameter names. Note
>   that the provided parameter name should have the exact casing as
>   declared on the method.

I'm not sure why this rule is so restrictive in that the argument has to be one of the method's parameters, and I can't use the class field.

I'm considering suppressing this warning, but I'd rather investigate why this is being called out.

Note: The MyString property is part of IMyInterface and cannot take this enum value as an argument.

Comment: I guess that an issue in `_myEnum` name and in fact that `MyString` property can't have any parameters

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski ahh yes

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: Well, that's only partially true. Within the *setter*, `"value"` would indeed be a valid parameter name.

Comment: You may wish to consider using the `Description` attribute on your enum members and just return that value instead of that clunky `switch` statement.  As it stands now, any time you change `MyEnum` you will have to remember to change the code in your property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm not sure why this rule is so restrictive in that the argument has to be one of the method's parameters

That's because whatever you pass in there will be published in the [`ParamName` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentexception.paramname) of the exception, which is defined as

> Gets the name of the parameter that causes this exception.

Now, if whatever is in there is *not* a parameter name, things can get confusing for whoever processes the exception. In a few cases, the `ArgumentException` and its `ParamName` might even be evaluated by means of reflection, which could fail if the parameter name is not found.

If you really want to supply a custom message to `ArgumentException`, you can use the [constructor that accepts a custom message and an exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentexception.-ctor#System_ArgumentException__ctor_System_String_System_Exception_) (and pass `null` for the exception).

**However**, as your exception does not indicate an invalid *argument*, I'd argue `ArgumentException` is not the right exception to use. You throw an exception because a property of your object has an invalid value - that is, because your object is in an invalid state. The correct exception to throw in this case is [`InvalidOperationException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.invalidoperationexception), which is defined as

> The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state.

(Note that your code being in the getter of a property counts as a "method call".)

---

As an aside, even if enum value were an argument, `ArgumentException` may not be the most appropriate choice. There is [`InvalidEnumArgumentException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.invalidenumargumentexception), which is specifically meant for use with enum values.

Comment: Great answer; I never really considered that this parameter is not technically an argument in this context.